# Overload order with (params T[]), (T param)

Tags: c#, parameters, overloading

The next methods are inside a class A inheriting from List< Class B >:

```
// Method A: Updates from specified start to end of list.
public void UpdateItems(int start = 0) {
    UpdateItems (
        Enumerable.Range (start, this.Count - start).ToArray ()
    );
}

// Method B: Updates separate indexes when necessary.
public void UpdateItems(params int[] indexes) {
    foreach (int i in indexes)
        this [i].id = i + 1;
}
```

Sometimes is necessary to update item properties(e.g. public int id) on different indexes and sometimes I just need a start-index and update from it to the end of the list. I came up with this simple two methods and everything was fine until I needed to use a simple param for `params` in method B, which was used as `start` for method A. I knew this was coming for they share the same name, still I wanted to test.

Questions:

- What is the best way to deal with this kind of cases? (i.e. You have overloaded methods for (params T[]) and (T param)). I know a simple name change is enough but I'd like a deeper opinion/solution.
- How is the overload resolution done?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for here, to be honest. Using clearer names, e.g. `UpdateItemRange` vs `UpdateItemsByIndex` seems like the best idea.

Comment: You *can* also disambiguate by including the parameter names ... but ... frankly I'd chose better method names... or make it not `params` - how often will you know the parameters explicitly at compile-time? not sure `params` is useful here...

Comment: After considering both MarcGravell and JonSkeet opinions I have made the proper changes and everything is cleaner and simpler. Thanks to both MVPs, I really appreciate your help and am actually a fan of both. I'll search more about this overload resolution on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can call the method with param name, for example

```
UpdateItems(indexes: 1); //Will call method with params
UpdateItems(1); //Will call method with start index
```

but in my opinion this is not a good solution. Would be better to have two methods with different names.

Also another way to call method with params would be passing array of integers as a method parameter

```
UpdateItems(new [] {1});
```